# Deploying Scheduled task to multiple computers via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to deploying a scheduled task to multiples computer in the network. So what the task does is that it will reboot the computers after idling for 1Hour + when the computer is locked.
I can't seem to deploy using the `-xml` parameter. 
the error i have included below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-05-02T14:35:05.1241005</Date>
    <Author>ANT\user</Author>
    <URI>\Reboot</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <SessionStateChangeTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <StateChange>SessionLock</StateChange>
      <Delay>PT1H</Delay>
    </SessionStateChangeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-1407069837-2091007605-538272213-32053677</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <WaitTimeout>PT1H</WaitTimeout>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>true</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>false</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>true</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>%SystemRoot%\system32\shutdown.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-r -f -t 10</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

```
$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task";
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)

$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content "C:\Reboot.xml" | Out-String) -TaskName "Reboot" -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password
```

Error return by PS$

```
Register-ScheduledTask : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\ermn\Desktop\P$.ps1:11 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content "C:\Reboot.xml" | Out-String ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Register-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: The error you posted says, that you are using parameters in the Register-ScheduledTask cmdlet that cannot be used togeather. According to the documentation for that cmdlet, it seems that you cannot use the runlevel parameter, when using the xml parameter. Furthermore you have declared the runlevel in your xml. Try removing the runlevel parameter from your command.

Comment: Hey @AxelAndersen thanks for responding! I'll give that a shot!

Comment: So i gave it a shot, and it worked well locally.

So i gave it a shot, and it worked well locally. But whenever i try to run it with the ```invoke-command``` , i get the follow error.
```Cannot find path "C:\Reboot.xml" because it does not exist.

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Xml'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and
then try the command again.```

Comment: If you are running the Invoke-Command with this scriptblock ```
Register-ScheduledTask -Xml (Get-Content "C:\Reboot.xml" | Out-String) -TaskName "Reboot" -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password``` you need to copy the xml files to the machines in your ComputerName property on Invoke-Command first. You will also encounter issues on username and password. This has developed into a different question then originally posted. It is not possible to follow the logic in the answers above. Please close the question and start a new on instead of changing the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you originally posted said, that you are using parameters in the Register-ScheduledTask cmdlet that cannot be used together.

According to the documentation for that cmdlet, it seems that you cannot use the runlevel parameter, when using the xml parameter.

Furthermore you have declared the runlevel in your xml. Remove the runlevel parameter from your command.